# Atom Error When Trying Commit in Local Repo (Even After Uninstalling Atom)

Tags: git, visual-studio, command-line, atom-editor

I switched from Atom (I purged atom from my machine) to Visual studio Code and now I'm getting this response in the command line after trying to make commits in my local repo:

> hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... atom --wait: atom: command not found error: Please supply the message using either -m or -F option."

**If I added files via Visual Studio Code why is Atom error feedback given?**

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the exact command you wrote in your command line?

Comment: git commit style.css.     it's staged but when I commit or push I receive same error feedback. sorry if this is a bad question but I can't seem to see what's probably obvious.

Comment: I did set the commit's message...

Comment: You told Git, presumably via `git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`, to use `atom`.  You then removed `atom`, without telling Git to stop using `atom`.  Git is still attempting to use `atom`, and failing. Why is this a surprise? Use `git config --global core.editor` to tell Git which editor you want  to use instead, now.

Comment: Thank you... and sorry for the question .. I thought I configured when I installed VS  code.. but apparently not.  should of reran before posting. Thanks for your time.